# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' 5

Tags: python-3.x

this is a small program just testing assignations and user input but i am having some trouble with it:

```
cars = input ("number of cars:")
space_in_a_car = 4.0
drivers = input ("number of drivers:")
passengers = input ("number of passengers:")
cars_not_driven = cars - drivers
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / cars_driven


print ("there are", cars, "cars available.")
print ("there are only", drivers, "drivers available.")
print ("there will be", cars_not_driven, "empty cars today.")
print ("we can transport", cars_not_driven, "people today.")
print ("we have", passengers, "to carpool today.")
print ("we need to put about", average_passengers_per_car, "in each car.")
```

when i run the program i get this:

```
number of cars:100
number of drivers:30
number of passengers:90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\src\finplay\cars program.py", line 5, in <module>
    cars_not_driven = cars - drivers
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

i cant seem to work out why this happens, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the error message? `input` gives you a string, not a number; you need to manually convert it to e.g. `int` or `float`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Chuckled a little at the concept of `float` for `cars` and `drivers` objects.

Comment: @admdrew well the OP has `4.0` spaces in a car!

Comment: @jonrsharpe True. And I'm sure this script needs to be able to support car crashes and dismemberment.

Comment: @admdrew lol im not sure how i'd go about doing that

Comment: @admdrew how would i go about using float? sorry if im being lazy and not consulting google :D

Comment: @TinnedWombat then why don't you not be lazy and consult Google?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't take a string away from a string. When you want the user to input a number instead of using `cars = input("Number of cars: ")` use `cars = int(input("Number of cars: "))`. Otherwise it's taking in text, not a number, and a bit like asking Python to subtract a driver from a car, or a cat from a dog.